# Groovy Mockito NullPointerException

Tags: java, groovy, mockito, powermockito

I have this java code:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Inject
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return anotherClass.getSomeValue().equals("true");
    }

}
```

Then I have the Groovy test class:

```
class TestServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

    private TestService testService;

    @Before
    void initMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        testService = new TestService()
    }

    void isEnabledTest() {
        when(anotherClass.getSomeValue()).thenReturn("true")
        assert testService.isEnabled() == true;
    }

}
```

The above test is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException on anotherClass.getSomeValue() statement in Java class. Looks like the TestClass is setup properly. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: won't anotherClass be null? as in, there's only a pointer to a class, not the initialised class?

Comment: @juju This is working fine in another test classes. I can't share the actual code. So, I replaced some variable names. Even anotherClass is a Service.

Comment: @AnirudhMergu doesn't add InjectMocks annotation helped.

Comment: @Ravindalakshan It helped, there was a constructor in my code already. I forgot to add anotherClass to that constructor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject your mocks. 
just add `@InjectMocks`

to  private TestService testService;

And you won't need  `testService = new TestService();`

```
class TestServiceTest {
@Mock
private AnotherClass anotherClass;

@InjectMocks
private TestService testService;

@Before
void initMock() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}

void isEnabledTest() {
    when(anotherClass.getSomeValue()).thenReturn("true")
    assert testService.isEnabled() == true;
}

}
```